# linux - running php script from command line when php is installed as apache module

Tags: php, linux, bash

Normally when I want to run a php script from the command line I just create a php page, add a shebang pointing to the php binary, then ./file.php to run it.  Since I have php installed as an apache module, I'm not even sure what my shebang should look like.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just an Apache module, I don't think you can do it… At least, not without using a script like this:

```
$ cat run_php_with_apache
#!/bin/sh
cp "$1" /var/www/
curl "http://localhost/`basename "$1"`"
rm "/var/www/`basename "$1"`"
```

Answer (score 12):

The CLI version of PHP had been part of the default installation since 4.3 and has to be explicitly turned off when PHP is being built.  If you have access to the command line try

```
$ php -v
```

If you don't get a command not found error then you should be ready to go.

To actually run a php file from the command line do this:

```
$ php -f file.php
```

Comment: then I think you are out of luck, they must have compiled PHP without the CLI support

Comment: what do you do if the system does not recognize PHP but you have PHP running?